# Change the color of Webkit progress value from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, progress-bar

For a school project I need to make a progress bar that changes color based on specific values. I know it is possible to give the progress bar colors in css using `::-webkit-progress-value` and `::-webkit-progress-bar`, but I need to know how to do this in javascript so i can change the colors dynamically.

This is what I have tried, but it does not seem to work.

```js
var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
progress.style['-webkit-progress-value'].background = 'red';
```

```html
<progress id="progress" value="0" min="0"></progress>
```

Thank you

Comment: What colours, at what percentages? How is the progress bar being made to  change?

Answer (score -1):

You could use data attribute CSS selectors to dynamically update the progress color.

I added multiple progress bars below, that finish at various times.

```js
const run = (progress, onUpdate, ms = 1000) => {
  progress = typeof progress === 'string' ?
    document.querySelector(progress) : progress;
  const updateStep = progress => {
    const
      val = progress.value,
      min = progress.min || 0,
      max = progress.max || 100,
      per = val / (max - min);
    if      (per > 0.66) { progress.dataset.step = 66; }
    else if (per > 0.33) { progress.dataset.step = 33; }
    else                 { progress.dataset.step = 0;  }
  }
  return new Promise(res => {
    updateStep(progress);
    const task = setInterval(() => {
      const
        min = progress.min || 0,
        max = progress.max || 100,
        val = progress.value;
      const newVal = onUpdate(val, min, max);
      progress.value = newVal;
      updateStep(progress);
      if (newVal >= max) {
        clearInterval(task);
        res(progress);
      } else {
        progress.value = newVal;
      }
    }, ms);
  });
}

const update = (val, min, max) => Math.round(val + ((max - min) / 10));
const done = ref => console.log(`Progress (id=${ref.id}) finished!`);

run('#progress-1', update).then(done);
run('#progress-2', update).then(done);
run('#progress-3', update).then(done);
```

```css
:root {
  --background: #111;
  --progress-background: #222;
  --progress-border: #333;
  --progress-step-0: #F00;
  --progress-step-33: #FF0;
  --progress-step-66: #0F0;
}

body {
  background: var(--background);
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 0.5em;
}

progress.color-progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

progress.color-progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #AAA;
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

progress.color-progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: var(--progress-background);
  border: thin solid var(--progress-border);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

progress.color-progress[data-step="0"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: var(--progress-step-0);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

progress.color-progress[data-step="33"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: var(--progress-step-33);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}

progress.color-progress[data-step="66"]::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: var(--progress-step-66);
  border-radius: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<progress id="progress-1" class="color-progress" value="0" min="0" max="100"></progress>
<progress id="progress-2" class="color-progress" value="50" min="0" max="100"></progress>
<progress id="progress-3" class="color-progress" value="50" min="25" max="75"></progress>
```

Comment: Not what the question has been asking for